# Can't understand the meaning of "flogged" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, synonyms, sentence

> There are products to be flogged and, Ms. Barberich added, “stars to be made.”

What does it mean by flogged here?
I got these synonym:
struck, propelled, electrical, beaten, flogged, chastised

Full Context for Original Quote: [Who Am I Wearing? Funny You Should Ask.](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/09/13/fashion/new-york-fashion-week-street-style-is-often-a-billboard-for-brands.html?ref=fashion)

Comment: [A related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/24201/3320). If anyone reading this has more light to shed on _how_ "flog" came to mean "sell" in parts of the UK, please share!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Flogged* is used here in wiktionary's sense 3 of *[flog](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flog)*,  “(transitive, UK) To sell something.”  That is, the sentence means there are products to be aggressively promoted and pushed into the faces of the public.

Answer (score 0):

> There are products to be flogged and, Ms. Barberich added, “stars to be made.”

The sentence means there is scope for a lot of products to be fiercely promoted/publicized in the market, and while it sells the new designers become stars.