# Flog meaning to sell in "Flogging a dead horse"

Tags: idioms, popular-refrains

I saw an article recently where the author used the term "flogging a dead horse" where the term flogging was meant in the UK slang sense of "to sell".
It was accompanied by a drawing of a stuffed horse being sold at market with a sign along the lines of "fast, living horse for sale". (I can't find the article again).

Is this usage of the phrase valid? I always thought that the phrase was a slight rewording of "beating a dead horse" where "flog"/"beat" would mean to physically hit.

Comment: You think quite correctly. This must have been a pun (not an unclever one, either).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think the pun you're seeing has flown a little over my head :P Would you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: Well, I don't know what the context is, but it seems pretty straightforward: take a well-known idiom and use one of the words in it in an alternative sense. The fact that it was accompanied by a cartoon just strengthens this theory: that is quite a typical type of pun in some cartoons/strips.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah I see what you mean now. Would you mind putting all that down as an answer so that the question can be closed if no one else has any ideas in the next few hours?

Comment: That's marketing for you!

Comment: Aww, why the downvote? I thought it was a valid question and I couldn't find any duplicates.

Comment: I'm surprised 'flogging a dead parrot' never really caught on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How did the slang meaning of "flog" come about?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24201/how-did-the-slang-meaning-of-flog-come-about)

Comment: @Merk I read that one before posting and it doesn't contain an answer to my question. My question acknowledges that flog can be used in both senses, I'm interested in whether the _idiom_ can be used in both senses

Comment: @Gricey I don't understand the issue here.  "Too many cooks spoil the broth."  There cooks/broth might be literal or metaphorical; it's still valid.  The picture next to the horse was just irony and not really part of the usage of the phrase either way.

Comment: @Merk that's exactly what I wanted to know as an answer, can someone please post something like that as an answer? I feel bad leaving answers in the comments especially after the recent community bulletin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly valid to say "flogging a dead horse" to mean "selling a dead horse", but "flogging a dead horse" is an idiom meaning you're doing something pointless: whipping a dead horse won't make it move any faster.

However, the drawing you saw must have been a comic making fun use of word-play by punning on two meanings of *flog*.

In normal use, however, you should stick the common meaning of the idiom. (But how often you do need to use the "selling a dead horse" meaning?)